# Python 3.5 and GLIBCXX_3.4.26 not found

Tags: python, linux, glibc

```sh
$ python3 view_model.py -f baselines -e resnet34imnet -cp 180000 -cv 0.9   
pygame 1.9.4   
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html    
Traceback (most recent call last):    
File "view_model.py", line 9, in   
from drive import CoILAgent   
File "/home/vaishu/coiltraine/drive/init.py", line 1, in   
from .coil_agent import CoILAgent    
File "/home/vaishu/coiltraine/drive/coil_agent.py", line 22, in    
from network import CoILModel    
File "/home/vaishu/coiltraine/network/init.py", line 3, in    
from .optimizer import adjust_learning_rate, adjust_learning_rate_auto    
File "/home/vaishu/coiltraine/network/optimizer.py", line 1, in    
import dlib    
ImportError: /home/vaishu/anaconda3/envs/chandan/bin/../lib/libstdc++.so.6:
version 'GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by /home/vaishu/anaconda3/envs/chandan/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dlib.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
```

Comment: Can you add the actual question and format the text

Answer (score 0):

Your anaconda environment is broken in some way.

As a first step make sure you've installed the correct version for your platform (I guess Mac OS X). Once done, set [LD_DEBUG](http://www.bnikolic.co.uk/blog/linux-ld-debug.html) environment variable to libs + files, start your python command again and make sure it picks native libraries from inside anaconda package and not somewhere else.

Comment: I reinstalled anaconda3 and set LD path but still, I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Is libstdc++.so loaded from anaconda installation? if not then that’s the problem